# Precautions while using pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Pointers are the core to programming languages like C and C++. This at the same time leads to many errors and memory leaks.
What are some precautions that must be taken while using pointers in C and C++?

Comment: Using pointers as such __doesn't__ lead to any memory leaks.

Comment: @PawełStawarz - no it is the "many errors and" that leads to the leaks. :-)

Comment: C/C++ isn't a language.. It's one or the other. I say this because one of the precautions I like to take is the RAII approach and use a Smart pointer which has nothing to do with C.. otherwise, always check if a pointer is null before accessing and set it to null after deleting in both C and C++.

Comment: Making errors while dealing with the pointers also __doesn't__ lead to any memory leaks. Pure pointers (without memory aloccation) can only lead to UB and accessing parts of the memory that aren't ment to :)

Comment: @PawełStawarz: `int *a; a = malloc(100); a = NULL; ` error. memory leak.

Comment: In C++ - just avoid pointers (or have them well encapsulated in a class or some shared_ptr/unique_ptr)

Comment: @Floris that example does __memory allocation__. If you don't allocate memory manually (so - no using `malloc`, `realloc`, `new`, and such), pointers themselves __can't__ cause a memory leak.

Comment: @PawełStawarz it was the pointer operation `a=NULL;` that was the cause of the memory leak. But I think we are splitting hairs. "Guns don't kill people; people with guns kill people".

Comment: Take a look at the many resources cited in the sidebar.

Comment: I don't think its a big problem in C++. C yes you actually need to think a lot about it and be careful. In C++ as long as you understand the ownership semantics of the systems its all pretty much automatic and a better version of garbage collection (deterministic cleanup of dynamic objects). The problem here is we still have people teaching C++ as a better version of C rather than its own separate language.

Comment: @Masked You really gotta decide, if you want to have an answer for [tag:c] **or** [tag:c++]. There are fundamental differences (at least by consens)!

Comment: Don't see how this question really is a dupe for the referenced one (what's written in the answers there is just **crap** compared to what has been gotten here already!!).

Comment: Pointers really aren't that hard. The only real precautions you need to take are to take some time to understand them and getting a good memory debugging tool like Valgrind, and you'll be set.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - excellent advice "use a good memory debugging tool".

Answer (score 1):

- Always initialize them
- Check the bounds (size of pointer offset / index)
- `free` the memory when done
- Set to `NULL` after freeing
- Check they are not `NULL` before accessing
- When you malloc, use `thing = malloc(N * sizeof *thing)`
- Don't overwrite a pointer that was `malloc`ed before you `free` it.
- ...

Comment: You should change the last one to "don't overwrite a pointer without freeing it first"

Comment: Sounds like c - not c++

Comment: @DieterLücking - absolutely. It's the half of `"C/C++"` that I vaguely understand.... and the one that most needs people to be careful about pointers (since there are so many cool things in C++ that are missing in C. Hence the `++` I suppose).

Comment: The answer covers the [tag:c] concerns all well, but doesn't cover [tag:c++] even partially ...

Comment: @pantarei - you are right; I focused on C because (a) I know it better and (b) it is more vulnerable, missing many of the protective C++ constructs you point out.

Answer (score 1):

Some good advice there in the comments and Floris' answer, but IMO "Don't use pointers" isn't one of them

shared_ptrs are great to protect against leaks but you can't always use them.  For example you are not supposed to use them with boost::intrusive containers.

additionally shared_ptrs wont help you if you have a container of said shared_ptrs and you just add but never remove from the container.  You still "leak" the resources, though you haven't lost the ability to remove it.

**other misc hints**:

As with all resources I find it best to minimize the code-paths by which one type can be allocated & freed, so that I can match them up in review and/or instrumentation.

when allocating c-strings don't forget to reserve room for your terminator

Comment: _'don't use pointers'_ is a really stupid, and too much narrowing advice!!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I think nhed is saying: "of all the good advice given, 'don't use pointers' isn't one of them". And he goes on to elaborate on that position. So the two of you are in agreement although your comment makes it look like you think you disagree.

Comment: plus-one for "minimize code paths by which you allocate / free". Keeping those things organized is very helpful to limit the ways that bugs can creep in. If you really hide the mechanisms you find yourself in C++ land...

Comment: @Floris It was meant as an agreement. As it stands that's a bit hard to get, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - OK thanks for the clarification! Question for you: how does one tag you in a reply when using mobile site? I don't get the autocomplete hint, and not sure if `@pantarei` will be correctly transliterated and mapped to πάνταῥεῖ by the notification service. Thoughts? See comment I made below my answer (written from phone). Wonder if you received that notification...

Comment: @Floris I didn't get a notification, but read it timely. Usually I'm checking back to my own comments/answers after a short while. I don't like to use SO from my smartphone/tablet so much, may be mainly because it's much harder to copy something (which I'm using a lot for comments or answers). There are other drawbacks, e.g. writing code samples works a lot better for me, if I'm using my laptop or development machine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's true that it is hard to use the site on mobile; but sometimes it's all I have... Agree with all you said.

Comment: Yes, we were in violent agreement, sorry I havent been on SO all day.  Also not sure how to edit and make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> Pointers are the core to programming languages like C and C++.

Not *'pointers'* necessarily, let's talk about references ...

**Note(!)** that the role of *'pointers'* has changed radically, when it comes to paradigms used in [c](/questions/tagged/c) vs. [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (especially for [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) language standards). So it would be difficult to handle them equally,

**As for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):**

The usage of 'raw' [c](/questions/tagged/c) pointers is strongly discouraged with programming in c++, at least when these are to be allocated dynamically with `new()` or `new[]()` (which are the main point of being prone causing memory leaks, within your applications).

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) the use of reference (see `&` and `&&` operators), which aren't available for [c](/questions/tagged/c), is preferred whenever possible (since they can't lead to such thing as a *'dangling reference'*  vs. a [*'dangling pointer'*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)).

The principle introduced in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is named [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c/395158#395158), and manages lifetime of any class instances mainly from the call stack scopes of any functions and execution paths present (no matter, if these are called within the same thread or not). I'm not saying that can't be implemented using just plain [c](/questions/tagged/c), but it's more difficult and error prone.

In a c++ application, the proper memory management for heap allocated class instances should be done using the [smart pointer facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)s of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), or at least the use of the good old (meanwhile deprecated) `std::auto_ptr` class, for pre c++11 standards.

> What are some precautions that must be taken while using pointers in C and C++?

There are some use cases for the usage of *raw pointers* in c++ of course (especially when interfacing between c and c++ APIs), but you should always test for their validity and know pretty good what you're actually doing! All the other cases are nicely covered by c++ standards, and you'll just need to use the right standard smart pointer class to get off from your problems.

Comment: This answer is plain confusion

Comment: @DieterLücking Is it? I'd **like** to improve it, because I see some differences of recommended handling of references in [tag:c] and [tag:c++] in general. Can you please elaborate which particular points to improve (for the [tag:c++] aspect, I've been mentioning in the beginning).

Comment: @DieterLücking ... Feel free to edit for improvement! (didn't manage to edit the comment above within the 5mins restriction)

Comment: @DieterLücking And as another point: **Confusion** of (tag:c and tag:c++) pointers and how to use them properly is ubiquitous (sorry I don't have a general answer for this point)!