# I insert struct to vector,but address of all the elements of vector are same

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I declared a struct treenode

```
struct treenode {
    int val;
    treenode *l;
    treenode *r;
};
```

and a vector

```
vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
```

now I want to create a vector tv to store the value of v

```
vector<treenode* > tv;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        treenode mid;
        mid.val = v[i];
        mid.l = NULL;
        mid.r = NULL;
        tv.push_back(&mid);
    }
```

but when I print the value of tv, I found all the element of tv are same(same address), there are 9. I`m confused, I　have create a new treenode every iteration, why all the element use same address
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmrC7.png)

Answer (score 4):

You have a vector of [dangling pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer). Just store them by value

```
vector<treenode> tv;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
{
    treenode mid;
    mid.val = v[i];
    mid.l = NULL;
    mid.r = NULL;
    tv.push_back(mid);
}
```

Otherwise you keep pushing back pointers to a temporary variable `mid` that falls out of scope between iterations.