# Array full of object pointers changes all pointers to in array to pointer that is just was just added

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

starting in actorAwarding.cpp, we add an actor object to actor db, a class that holds a BST, Max heap and dynamicall allocated array

```
void do_register_actor(int actor_id, string actor_last, string actor_first)
{

   Actor a(actor_id, actor_last, actor_first);
   if (actordb.addActor(a))
   {
      Actor *actor_ptr = &a;
      actordb.actor_to_heap(actor_ptr);
      cout << "register_actor: Registered actor " << a.getName() << endl;
   }
   else
      cout << "register_actor: Error actor id " << actor_id << " already in use" << endl;
   return;
}
```

in ActorDB.cpp we add a pointer object to out max heap (actors_award)

```
void ActorDB::actor_to_heap(Actor *actor)
{   
    actors_award.insert(actor);
}
```

we also have addActor which adds it to the BST,I was using it here but decide to make a individual function, regardless the issue persisted

```
bool ActorDB::addActor(Actor &actor)
{

    // Actor *ptr = &actor;

    // actors_award.insert(actor);
    unsigned int actorID = actor.getID();
    string lastname = actor.getLastName();
    unsigned int insertPosition = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < actors.getSize(); i++)
    {

        if (actors[i].getID() == actorID)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (actors[i].getID() > actorID)
        {
            insertPosition = i;
            break;
        }
        insertPosition++;
    }

    cout << insertPosition << endl;

    /*
      Node* bstRoot = actor_tree.getRoot();

      if (!bstRoot) {
          actor_tree.setRoot(actor_tree.BSTInsert(bstRoot, lastname, insertPosition));
      } else {
          actor_tree.BSTInsert(bstRoot, lastname, insertPosition);
      }

      Node* searchedNode = actor_tree.search(bstRoot, lastname);
      actor.set_BSTcounterpart(searchedNode);

      if (insertPosition == actors.getSize()) {
          actors.add(actor);
      } else {
          actors.addAtActors(insertPosition, actor);
      }
      */

    if (insertPosition == actors.getSize())
    {
        if (!actor_tree.getRoot())
        {
            actor_tree.setRoot(actor_tree.BSTInsert(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname, insertPosition));
        }
        else
        {
            actor_tree.BSTInsert(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname, insertPosition);
        }

        // Search for the node in the BST to get the counterpart
        Node *searchedNode = actor_tree.search(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname);
        // cout << searchedNode->index << " please" << endl;
        actor.set_BSTcounterpart(searchedNode);

        // cout << actor.get_BSTcounterpart()->index << " something " << endl;

        // Add the actor to the dynamic array
        actors.add(actor);
        // actors_award.insert(actor);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!actor_tree.getRoot())
        {
            actor_tree.setRoot(actor_tree.BSTInsert(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname, insertPosition));
        }
        else
        {
            actor_tree.BSTInsert(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname, insertPosition);
        }

        Node *searchedNode = actor_tree.search(actor_tree.getRoot(), lastname);

        actor.set_BSTcounterpart(searchedNode);

        actors.addAtActors(insertPosition, actor);
        //  actors_award.insert(actor);
    }

    // Actor* ptr = *actors
    return true;
}
```

next we have the max heap, THIS is where the problem is happening, I orignally taking a reference to actor object but problem was still there regardless. I obvi have other functionality for the max heap but i am only using insert for now to figure the problem out since the problem persisted with full functionality

```
    void maxHeap::insert(Actor *actorb)
{

   
    //cout << actorb -> getName() <<  endl;
    //Actor *actor_ptr =  &actor;
    // problem still persisted when i initalized a pointer inside insert ^
    max_heap.add(actorb);
   // cout << " in insert    " << actor.getName() << "  size:" << max_heap.getSize() << endl;
    if (max_heap.getSize() == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    
}
```

max_heap is a dynamically allocated array from templated class temp_arr, from this class am only using add and op[], my capacity starts at 10 but am not inputting more than 10 objects , so resizing is not included

```
template<typename T>
void temp_arr<T>::add( T& element) {
    // Add implementation
    // Add an element to the array, resizing if necessary

   if(size == capacity - 1 ){
    resize();
   }


    array[size] = element;


     size++;

}
template<typename T>
T& temp_arr<T>::operator[](unsigned int index){
     if (index >= size) {
        // Out-of-bounds check
        throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
        // Alternatively, you can handle this case differently, like returning a default value or throwing an exception
    }

    return array[index];

 }
```

Ive tried perfecting copy contructors and putting ad to heap in different functions in max heap the issue still persists. Whats weird:

1
travolta
IN actor_to_heap, current actor we are trying to add:  john travolta

addr:
0000028645781ab0 john travolta

In Heap insert, size:  1
addr:
0000028645781ab0 john travolta

addr:
0000028645781ab8 john travolta
register_actor: Registered actor john travolta

: 2
lander
IN actor_to_heap, current actor we are trying to add:  home lander

addr:
0000028645781ab0 home lander

addr:
0000028645781ab8 home lander
In Heap insert, size:  2

addr:
0000028645781ab0 home lander
addr:

0000028645781ab8 home lander
addr:

0000028645781ac0 home lander

register_actor: Registered actor home lander
: 3

hepburn
IN actor_to_heap, current actor we are trying to add:  audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ab0 audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ab8 audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ac0 audrey hepburn
In Heap insert, size:  3
addr:

0000028645781ab0 audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ab8 audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ac0 audrey hepburn
addr:

0000028645781ac8 audrey hepburn

When i print the max_heap in actor_to_heap (adds actor to max heap in actorDB) the pointers in max_heap are already pointing to that actor. How is this possible? I am SURE i am not adding to the anywhere else, I am tripple decker sure. Also my temp_arr works fine for BST and the array in actorDB. any ideas?

Comment: With `Actor *actor_ptr = &a;` and `actordb.actor_to_heap(actor_ptr);` you save a pointer to a local variable. Once the func tion returns and the life-time of `a` ends, the pointer you have saved will become invalid. Why are you saving pointers instead of objects directly? In C++ there's seldom a need to use raw C-style non-owning pointers. Either store object directly, or use owning smart pointers if pointer are really needed (which is seldom outside the need for polymorphism and custom data-structures).

Comment: yep i guess that approach is wrong too and silly of me but I did have actordb.actor_to_heap( Actor &actor);
insertn( Actor &actor);
and creates a pointer in insert in max heap if you look at the comments in insert but that didn't work either, I still had the same issue

Comment: i think am going to go back to using objects, I switched because I have other functionality where I have to change data members in Actor objects. This bug is a headache but interesting :{

Comment: @yisel You are making the exact same mistake where you comment `// problem still persisted when i initalized a pointer inside insert ^`. As the previous comment says, make `max_heap` store `Actor`, not `Actor*`. Or, if you need polymorphism, have it store `std::unique_ptr<Actor>` and create the objects with `std::make_unique`.

Comment: @yisel "_I switched because I have other functionality where I have to change data members in Actor objects._": What does this have to do with whether or not the object is stored directly or as a pointer?

Comment: "_Ive tried perfecting copy contructors_": It is usually not necessary to manually write copy constructors. It is unlikely that `Actor` or `ActorDB` should have one. Follow the rule-of-zero as much as possible and the rule-of-three/five only for classes that directly encapsulate individual resources or that are custom data structures with strict storage control requirements or deeply nested.

Comment: @yisel *"creates a pointer in insert in max heap"* -- Creating a pointer is trivial and does **not** transform a local variable to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: You really should take some time to remove unnecessary processing from your [mre]. You've identified the problem as the objects having the same address, so skip everything else. Add a `main` function that calls `do_register_actor` twice, keep the demonstration that the addresses are the same, but drop everything else. In particular, `addActor` would just compare the new entry to the previous one, store the new entry, then return if the entries were the same. No checking for duplicates or sorting or anything else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I insert struct to vector,but address of all the elements of vector are same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596430/i-insert-struct-to-vector-but-address-of-all-the-elements-of-vector-are-same)

Comment: Hi guys, thank u so much for the comments. using your responses abt using pointers, I was able to identify the problem. Instead of me pointing to an Actor object that will go out of scope, I am pointing to actor object inside an array in ACTORDB. I think am thinking of this right but it seemed to work. Although I  am still using pointers, I've learned that regardless using Actor objects directly was the best approach. again thank you

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if you declare a variable x within a function, x is only visible within that function body.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170

So, you created your local `a` variable inside your function, so it has local scope:

> Local scope A name declared within a function or lambda, including the parameter names, have local scope. They are often referred to as "locals". They are only visible from their point of declaration to the end of the function or lambda body. Local scope is a kind of block scope, which is discussed later in this article.

Your local variable is destroyed when your function exits, therefore returning the pointer like you did is undefined behavior and is causing you headaches. This is therefore bad practice and you should work with objects rather than unowned pointers to said objects.

> i think am going to go back to using objects, I switched because I have other functionality where I have to change data members in Actor objects

Then that's your real problem. You wanted to solve it in the manner you described, but now that you know that this manner is invalid, you should return to your point of departure and find a different, valid solution to this problem.

I wonder what you wanted to change in the first place. If you speak only about the values of data members, then that's not really a problem in C++. But, if you speak about what your data members are, then it sounds like bad design. You may create another class or other classes, you may use inheritance, etc. So the answer to your question is that your current approach to solve your problem is invalid, so the earlier you return to your point of departure, the better for you.