# Elements in array keep changing unintentionally

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have two arrays which hold players x, y and z co-ordinates, however each time I call them they change their values the first time they are printed to the console they display the correct result however subsequent prints to the screen yield very small numbers,

```
HisPosition = GetPlayerPosition(aPlayer);
std::cout << "TheirPos=" << std::dec << HisPosition[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "TheirPos1=" << std::dec << HisPosition[0] << std::endl;

if(!isnan(HisPosition[0])){
    std::cout << "TheirPos2=" << std::dec << HisPosition[0] << std::endl;
```

Example console output:

```
TheirPos=440
TheirPos1=1.7118e-037
TheirPos2=1.7118e-037
```

They are defined like so:

```
float* HisPosition;
```

And GetPlayerPosition:

```
float* GetPlayerPosition(DWORD dwBase)
{
    float result [3];
    DWORD aXPos = dwBase + 0x134;
    DWORD aYPos = dwBase + 0x138;
    DWORD aZPos = dwBase + 0x13C;

    result[0] = Read<float>(aXPos);
    result[1] = Read<float>(aYPos);
    result[2] = Read<float>(aZPos);

    return result;
}
```

aPlayer stands for the address in memory of the player I am trying to fetch the offsets are correct as on the first console print the position is correct.

I'm new to using arrays in C++ and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: `return result;` returns a pointer to an array which is then immediately destroyed on the return.  You have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return result;` returns a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer) to local, stack-allocated array that gets vanished when goes out of scope.

Comment: Cheers how can I make sure it remains so it doesn't vanish? Edit: My bad just looked at the duplicate. Not going to lie I had no Idea what to search.

Comment: @JossBird For example: by returning object instead of pointer. You can even name the elements properly instead using [0] ...

Comment: You can return ::std::array class with 3 floats instead of raw pointer or maybe define a `Position` class to hold coordinated and return it.

Comment: @KIIV and VTT you're both genius's I created a new struct and now everything works perfectly! Thank you so much!