# Why using this way the class is wrong?

Tags: c++11

I have been told that creating a class like this is wrong without a given explanation and after spending a significant amount of time, I cannot figure out the reason.

```
class Dog {
public:
    Dog (char const* n) : dog_name(n) {}
    ~Dog() {}

    char const* getDogName() const 
    { 
        return dog_name; 
    }

private:
    char const* dog_name;
};
```

Comment: Probably object lifetime. `dog_name` is pointing to... something. We can't tell what, or what its lifetime is. It might end up being a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code using your class:

```
char *name = new char[5];
strcpy(name, "Fido");
Dog fido(name);
delete name;
std::cout << fido.getDogName() << '\n'; // Oops -- undefined behavior!
```

The instance `fido` is still pointing at a `char` array that has been deleted. This is a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer), which leads to [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Or another problem:

```
char name[32];
strcpy(name, "Fido");
Dog fido(name);
strcpy(name, "Rover");
Dog rover(name);
std::cout << fido.getDogName() << '\n'; // Why does this print "Rover"?
std::cout << rover.getDogName() << '\n';
```

Here both instances are pointing at the same buffer. When you changed it, it changed Fido's name to Rover. Oops.

One solution would be to create your own `char` buffer in the class instead of just a pointer and `strcpy` the data into it (carefully range checking so you don't overrun the buffer!). Or just avoid all this nonsense and use `std::string`, which makes a lot more sense.