# Losing some data after leaving function

Tags: c++

I've got a class which contains these vectors:

```
class MainMenu {

private:
     std::vector <Car> vehicles;
     std::vector <Instructor> instructors;
     std::vector <Trainee> trainees;
     std::vector <Lesson> lessons;
public:
     std::vector<Car>& getVehicles();
     std::vector<Instructor>& getInstructors();
     std::vector<Trainee>& getTrainees();
     std::vector<Lesson>& getLesson();
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------

```
class Car : public Vehicle {

public:
    static MARKA convertStringToMarka(std::string name);
    Car(std::string numberPlate, MARKA marka, bool roadWorthy);
    Car() {};
    Car(int id,std::string numberPlate, MARKA marka, bool roadWorthy);

};
```

And somewhere in the code i perform such function:

```
Car *car = mainMenu.searchForCarById(idOfVehicle);

Car* MainMenu::searchForCarById(int id) {
     for (Car elem : vehicles) {
         if (elem.getIdInSystem() == id) {
             return &elem;
         }
    }
}
```

While debugging i perform this code step by step, and this simply function search for car's correctly but whenever I return from funtion, every variable which was string dissapear. For example in `name` variable I recieve `""`. I think it is important to mention that only strings dissapear! int stays as it was. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are returning an address of a local variable, which is is erased after you live the function. This is undefined behavior. In your case, you should make your `elem` a reference - this would work fine, and have an added benefit of removing unnecessary copy.

Comment: You also have a "not all code paths return a value" error in `searchForCarById()`. Next time please provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have private class members, and then provide public accessors that return mutable references? Might as well make those class members public to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Change this line

```
for (Car elem : vehicles)
```

to

```
for (Car& elem : vehicles)
```

otherwise you are saving a pointer to a local variable that falls out of scope, therefore working against a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Answer (score 4):

```
for (Car elem : vehicles)
```

`elem` is a copy of the actual object contained in `vehicles`. You then return a pointer to this local object which is destroyed, leaving it dangling. The fix is to use `Car&` instead.

Answer (score 4):

When you loop through your vehicles, the following line:

```
for (Car elem : vehicles)
```

makes a copy of each element and stores it in elem.

Instead, try getting the element by reference:

```
for (Car& elem : vehicles)
```

Then, you can actually get a pointer. However, This pointer might become invalid as soon as you modify your array. So it's still not optimal.