# C++ std::stringstream to const char* conversion

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, string-conversion

I am trying to convert a `stringstream` into a `const char*`, but I always get a blank string.

My Code:

```
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<stdio.h>

const char* test(std::string city, std::string street, int houseNumber, int postCode) {
std::stringstream ss;
ss << city << " " << street << " " << houseNumber << " " << postCode;
const std::string tmp =  std::string{ss.str()};
const char* str = tmp.c_str();
return str;
}

int main(){
printf(test("demo", "Demo", 1, 1234));
}
```

Expected Output: `demo Demo 1 1234`

I tried all the enhancements mentioned in [How to convert a std::string to const char* or char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/how-to-convert-a-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char), but I had no success.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the stream to a `cons char*`?  Can yo show what you need that for?

Comment: If you're using C++ you shouldn't be using `printf`.  Use `cout` instead.  That works with `std::string`

Comment: [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [an a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the string data your `const char*` points to has been freed after the `return str;`. The `const char*` pointer will stay valid as long as the associated `std::string` instance is within scope. This is assuming the code you have shown here is located within a function. In that case, the string `tmp` will go out of scope after the `return str;`, and its destructor will be called, causing any pointer pointing to its character data to become a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

Return an `std::string`, and call `c_str()` on the returned string instead. As mentioned, you can then use the `const char*` pointer as long as the associated `std::string` instance is within scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering is that when this function leaves scope (i.e. when `return str;` executes), the memory `str` points to will have been cleaned up. You need to return an object that will maintain ownership over the data.

```
//std::string_view is >=c++17, use std::string const& for older compilers
std::string get_formatted_address(
    std::string_view city, 
    std::string_view street, 
    std::string_view houseNumber, 
    std::string_view postCode
) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << city << " " << street << " " << houseNumber << " " << postCode;
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    auto city = "New York", street = "Rockefeller Lane", houseNumber = "1234", postcode = "56789";
    auto formatted_address = get_formatted_address(city, street, houseNumber, postcode);
    //Here, formatted_address holds ownership over the memory, so calling c_str is safe
    printf("Address: %s\n", formatted_address.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn dangling references into non-dangling references by using `static thread_local` to store a temporary object.

Note that you will only be able to have one active "non dangling" reference at a time:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

const char* to_cstr(std::string && s)
{
    static thread_local std::string sloc;
    sloc = std::move(s);
    return sloc.c_str();
}

const char* make_address(std::string const& city, 
                         std::string const& street, 
                         std::string const& houseNumber, 
                         std::string const& postCode)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << city << " " << street << " " << houseNumber << " " << postCode;
    return to_cstr(std::move(ss).str());
}

int main()
{
    const char* p = make_address("London","Bob Street","42","W1ABC");
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
London Bob Street 42 W1ABC
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/228e6c0cb8359222