# Adding a string-type class member causes base class function to be called instead of child

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Why does the following code print 0, but if you comment out "std::string my_string" it prints 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    virtual int foo() {
      return 0;
    }
  private:
    std::string my_string;
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    int foo() {
      return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a;
    if (true) {
      B b;
      a = &b;
    }
    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I also understand that changing std::string to std:string* also causes the code to print 1, as does removing the if-statement, though I don't understand why any of that is true.

EDIT: This seems to be due to a dangling pointer. Then what's the standard pattern in C++ to do something like this in Java:

```
Animal animal; 
boolean isDog = false; 
// get user input to set isDog 
if (isDog) { 
  animal = new Dog();
} else {
  animal = new Cat();
}
animal.makeNoise(); // Should make a Dog/Cat noise depending on value of isDog.
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. You're trying to use a local variable that has gone out of scope.

Comment: Interesting. Then what's the standard pattern in C++ to do something like this in Java:

Animal animal;

boolean isDog = false;
// get user input to set isDog

if (isDog) {
  animal = new Dog();
} else {
  animal = new Cat();
}

Comment: @Hydra 1) If you used `new` - it wouldn't be a dangling pointer, and it would've worked fine. Note: you would be required to `delete` it, though. Hence, your comparison with Java code is not equivalent (even if it is similar). it's like asking why apples taste different to oranges, if they are both round. 2) C++ is not Java.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius If you post an answer with a corrected version of my code using new then I will accept it as the correct answer. Sorry I am not sure where I would delete the pointer if it only exists within the if scope.

Comment: @Hydra 1) There already was an answer, explaining the issue, at the time of me writing the comment. I was merely responding to your Java snippet, not being equivalent to your C++ snippet. 2) What do you mean by "_Sorry I am not sure where I would delete the pointer if it only exists within the if scope._"? It doesn't. Such a question suggests, that you are not familiar with C++ language fundamentals (such as: object lifetime), and you should learn them from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Problem

The program has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `b` is only in scope inside the body of the `if`. You can't count on logical results when accessing a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

```
int main()
{
    A* a;
    if (true) {
      B b; // b is scoped by the body of the if.
      a = &b;
    } // b's dead, Jim.
    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl; // a points to the dead b, an invalid object
    return 0;
}
```

## TL;DR Solution

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a; // All hail the smart pointer overlords!
    if (true) {
      a = std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
} // a is destroyed here and takes the B with it.
```

## Explanation

You can point `a` at an object with a dynamic lifetime

```
int main()
{
    A* a;
    if (true) {
      a = new B; // dynamic allocation 
    } // b's dead, Jim.
    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl; 
    delete a; // DaANGER! DANGER!
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately `delete a;` is also undefined behaviour because `A` has a non-`virtual` destructor. Without a virtual destructor the object pointed at by `a` will be destroyed as an `A`, not as a `B`.

The fix for that is to give `A` a virtual destructor to allow it to destroy the correct instance.

```
class A {
  public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual int foo() {
      return 0;
    }
  private:
    std::string my_string;
};
```

There is no need to modify `B` because once a function is declared `virtual`, it stays `virtual` for its children. [Keep an eye out for `final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final).

But it's [best to avoid raw dynamic allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new), so there is one more improvement we can make: [Use Smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

And that brings us back to the solution.

[Documentation for `std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

[Documentation for `std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)