# What is address of local variable ‘a’ returned?

Tags: c++, c++11

1. I don’t know what is wrong with the following code.
2. It tells address of local variable returned.

```cc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *myfunc(int *ptrB);

int main() {
    int *a, b;
    cout << "give b :" << endl;
    cin >> b;
    a = myfunc(&b);
    cout << "a is :" << *a << endl;
    return 0;
}

int *myfunc(int *ptrB) {
    int a; 
    a= (*ptrB) * (*ptrB);
    *ptrB = a;
    return &a;
}
```

Comment: Why do you return a pointer to the variable instead of returning it by value?

Comment: `int a;` in `myfunc` is destroyed as soon as the function returns, so the pointer to it (that was returned) is invalid and can't be used for anything useful.

Comment: Look up what is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) in C++. Because, that's a local variable you are returning, so the pointer is most probably dangling

Comment: The actual address of `a` returned could be different everytime, so we can't tell you what the value will be. I suspect that it will be an address on the stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Comment: At least for C,  (and I suspect C++) even the equivalent C code of `cout << "address a is :" << a << endl;` is UB.

Answer (score 3):

"I don't know what is wrong." - What is wrong is that you are returning the address of a local variable that ceases to exist once the function returns, so that address points to a dead object and trying to use it is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: As a minor, maybe insignificant addition. Someone took the time to write this severely convoluted piece of code, well knowing it would be invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do anything with a pointer that is returned by a function, like dereference it, which is a typical thing to do with a pointer, you need to know that the object that your pointer points to exists.  However, the pointer you return points to an object that exists in scope of the returning function; after the function has returned, the function scope no longer exists and the object goes down with it.  It is like holding an address of a house that has been demolished and hoping you can spend the night there.

Comment: thanks a lot the house explanation is awesome!