# Why static vector of pointer to objects of a class is having garbage values?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, casting

I am doing a project on OOPs in C++ and getting some errors (Segmentation Fault).

`sObjects` is a static vector containing pointers to every object created in the `Base` class.

I have also checked the addresses by uncommenting the lines :
`// cout<<(*it)<<endl;`
`// cout<<this<<endl;`
.They are same.

So why I am getting garbage values/segmentation fault ?
Do I have to do some sort of casting?

Here is my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    Base::UnitTest();

    vector<Base *>::iterator it;
    for (it = Base::sObjects.begin(); it < Base::sObjects.end(); ++it)
    {
        // cout<<(*it)<<endl;
        cout<<(*(*it))<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
//Base.h
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int val;
};

class Base
{
private:
    Node node_;
public:
    Base(int a=0);
    ~Base();

    static vector<Base*> sObjects;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Base &myObj);

    static void UnitTest();
};

#endif
```

```
//Base.cpp
#include "Base.h"
vector<Base*> Base::sObjects;

Base::Base(int a)
{
    this->node_.val=a;
    sObjects.push_back(this);
    // cout<<this<<endl;
}

Base::~Base()
{
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Base &myObj)
{
    os<<myObj.node_.val;
    return os;
}

void Base::UnitTest()
{
    Base obj(23);
}
```

Comment: You are not externing ```sObjects```. How is this even compiling?

Comment: I am creating a sample object of base class in the UnitTest of Base class with value 23, but the values printing in terminal are garbage.

Comment: The object created in `Base::UnitTest()` goes out of scope however you keep its pointer in your vector after it no longer exists. This is an instance of a dangling pointer. This is undefined behavior / anything can happen including it appearing to work some of the time. Thankfully you found that it does not work in your case. It would have been much worse if it appeared to work even though it was broken.

Comment: @user2233706 It's compiling without any error. Just the values printed are garbage

Comment: The values printed are garbage because the vector has a dangling pointer after the object pointed to is destructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object created in `Base::UnitTest()` goes out of scope however you keep its pointer to it using `sObjects.push_back(this);` in your vector after it no longer exists. This is an instance of a dangling pointer. This is  undefined behavior. Anything can happen including it appearing to work some of the time. Thankfully you found that it does not work in your case. It would have been much worse if it appeared to work even though it was broken.

Related: [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Also: [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a)

In the also link this is a case of using a pointer who's lifetime has ended. ***Using pointers to objects whose lifetime has ended (for instance, stack allocated objects or deleted objects)***

Answer (score 0):

The object is created in the scope of `Base::UnitTest()`. So you are saving the pointer the memory in the function stack call of `Base::UnitTest()` in `Base::sObjects`. To avoid this behaviour you may remove the pointer from `Base::sObjects` when the objects no longer exists. i.e., you may remove during the destrction of the object (in destructor).