# Incorrect values for overloading multiplication by scalar for a simple Polynomial class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Simplifying: I am trying to write a simple `Polynomial` class and I get incorrect values when I try to overload the multiplication operator:

```
#include <iostream>

class Polynomial {

  public:

    unsigned int degree;
    int *coefficients;

    Polynomial(unsigned int deg, int* arr) {
        degree = deg;
        coefficients = arr;
    }

    ~Polynomial() {}

    int& operator[](int index) const {
        return coefficients[index];  
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Polynomial& P){
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < P.degree; i++) os << P[i] << ",";
    os << P.coefficients[P.degree];
    return os;
}

Polynomial operator*(const Polynomial &P, const int &x) {
    int arr[P.degree];
    for (unsigned int i=0; i <= P.degree; i++) arr[i] = P[i];
    Polynomial p(P.degree, arr);
    std::cout << p << std:: endl; // just for debugging
    return p;
}
```

I am testing the code in my `main`:

```
    int g[] = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1};
    Polynomial P_g = Polynomial(10, g);

    std::cout << P_g << std::endl;
    Polynomial P_g_3 = P_g*3;

    std::cout << P_g_3[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[4] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[5] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[6] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[7] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[8] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[9] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3[10] << std::endl;
    std::cout << P_g_3 << std::endl;
```

But the output in the console is something totally different then what I expect:

```
-1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,-1
-1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,-1
-1
0
0
0
0
0
-2002329776
32767
-516177072
32766
539561192
0,32766,539581697,32767,-2002329776,32767,1,0,243560063,1,-2002329776
```

Although notice that the inner `cout` statement from within the overloaded operator returns a correct polynomial. Only when the program exits that function the coefficients get screwed... Moreover the two printing strategies are not even consistent with themselves. What is going on?

Comment: 1. Stop using VLA extension `int arr[P.degree];`   2. Access out of bounds: `i <= P.degree;`

Comment: 3. Using address of a temporary object You are giving the constructed object the address of an array that will no longer exist when the function has finished.

Comment: It seems _very weird_ for your Polynomial class to not actually own its coefficients. Suggestion: Instead of an `int*`, make `coefficients` a `std::vector<int>`. That will also make it much easier to implement the copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor (that is: the compiler-generated ones will be correct, instead of wrong as they are now). It'll also save you from errors like allocating space for `degree` many coefficients when a degree `d` polynomial has `d+1` coefficients.

Comment: I see. OK, I will re-write the array management. However, I don't think I am accessing anything out of bounds here. The array has 11 elem. The degree passed to the constructor is 10 so at the end of the loop `i <= P.degree;` correctly points to the last element of an array.

Comment: *"when the program exits that function the [bad thing happens]"* -- this symptom is typical of trying to access a variable local to the function. So it would be useful to look at the local variables in the function. What are they and where are they used? Do you store any pointers or references to any of them?

Comment: Hmm... I've found several questions with the same underlying mistake, but none of them look appropriate to propose as a duplicate. Maybe someone else will have better luck. (If not, I am willing to post an answer later.) In the meantime, I'll suggest reading [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228) and observe that if you switch to using `std::vector`, your problem will likely disappear.

Comment: Why do you think the array has `11` elements? `int arr[P.degree];` when `P.degree` is `10` will be a `10`-element array, whose last element is at index `9`.

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis

Your `Polynomial` class is rather unusual in that it does not own its own data. While this is not inherently wrong, it is almost always an unwise approach.

As an illustration, look at the variables in your main function. The data for the polynomial `P_g` is stored in the array `g`. The variable `g` serves no purpose other than storing that data, so its name is clutter. There is also a consistency concern here, because if someone were to change an element of `g`, then `P_g` would also change. Even worse, if `g` were to cease to exist while `P_g` was still around, you would have a polynomial without access to its data!

Fortunately, local variables are destroyed in the reverse order of creation, so `P_g` will be destroyed before `g`. However, no such luck intervenes when you invoke `operator*`. In that operator, the polynomial `p` stores its data in the local variable `arr`. So far, the situation is the same as in `main()`. Until you return `p`. At that point, `p` is copied/moved into the calling scope, and that copy uses the same data as the original. The array `arr` gets destroyed, yet the returned object still tries to access `arr` for its data. The returned object, `P_g_3`, has [a dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer).

When you try to access the data of `P_g_3`, undefined behavior occurs. In some cases, you might see the behavior you expect. In this case, garbage values were produced. From one perspective, your result is the more desirable one since you were able to detect that a problem exists, which allowed you to attempt to fix it. Far more insidious is the undefined behavior that performs as you expect when you run the program, but not when someone else does.

### Solution

The usual approach is to have objects own their own data. Often, this is exclusive ownership, so that the data cannot change without going through the object.

A first refinement would be to move the data-holding arrays into the objects. The main obstacle is that you do not know in advance how large the array is. This calls for dynamic memory allocation. You could start down this road without changing the data members of your class; a first step might be to initialize `coefficients` to memory allocated with `new` rather than assigning it `arr`. This leads to the need to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). Unfortunately, this is a bit of work to do correctly, especially since you have chosen to track the degree of the polynomial instead of the size of the array.

Fortunately, storing data of unknown length is a common concern, common enough that the standard library provides tools to automate most of the details. One such tool is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If you change the type of `coefficients` from `int*` to `std::vector<int>`, then `Polynomial` objects will be able to own their own data, *plus* the Rule of Three becomes the Rule of Zero. (That is, the compiler-generated destructor and copy methods will suffice.) Your `operator*` could simply make a copy of the incoming `Polynomial`, then iterate over the copy's vector to make changes.

As an added benefit, you no longer need to track `degree` manually, as the degree of non-zero polynomials will be `coefficients.size() - 1`. (Well, there is a complication if the leading coefficient is zero, but that's also an unhandled concern for your original implementation.) This demonstrates one reason a class will often keep its data members `private`. If you had made the data member private and instead defined a `degree()` method, you could change how the degree is determined without modifying any code that uses `Polynomial`.

**Note:**
If you use [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with your vectors, the example code would have no need to look at the degree of a polynomial. You would be providing the member function for the benefit of code external to the class.