# Structure data changes when using constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, user-defined-types

The first code works as expected. I am trying to work with double pointers inside structures.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int val) {
        data = val;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

struct Triplet{
    Node** node;
    int pval, lchild;
};

int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(10);

    Triplet t;
    t.node = &root;
    t.pval = 1001;
    t.lchild = 2;
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the correct and expected output

```
10 1001 2
10 1001 2
10 1001 2
```

But when I try to use the same logic but with constructor, then I get random values after the first `cout` is called. This is not limited to `cout` but rather if the **double-pointer** is accessed once, it will change for the next calls.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int val) {
        data = val;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

struct Triplet{
    Node** node;
    int pval, lchild;
    Triplet(){}
    Triplet(Node* temp, int a, int b){
        node = &temp;
        pval = a;
        lchild = b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(10);

    Triplet t(root, 1001, 2);
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    cout << (*t.node)->data << " " << t.pval << " " << t.lchild << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Unusual output :

```
10 1001 2
1878374340 1001 2
1878374340 1001 2
```

Comment: `node = &temp;` - you are taking address of parameter. It dies as soon as constructor finishes.

Comment: "I am trying to work with double pointers inside structures." Why?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/7509065)

Comment: You haven't **only** added a constructor -- you also changed `&root` to `root`.  That's causing the change.

Comment: Print `&root` in `main` and `&temp` in the constructor and compare them.

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/7509065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your non-constructor version, `t.node` holds the address of `root`.

```
t.node = &root;
```

In your constructor version, `t.node` holds the address of `temp`, which is indeed a temporary.  It becomes a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer) once `temp` no longer exists.

```
node = &temp;
```

In order to match your non-constructor version, your constructor needs to take a `Node**`.

```
struct Triplet{
    Node** node;
    int pval, lchild;
    Triplet(){}
    Triplet(Node** temp, int a, int b){
        node = temp;
        pval = a;
        lchild = b;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Node *root = new Node(10);

    Triplet t(&root, 1001, 2);
```