# How to access values from a pointer-to-array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am using the dereference operator but I don't seem to getting values of x.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array {

  public:
  int* get() {
      int x[] = { 31, 45, 39, 32, 9, 23, 75, 80, 62, 9 }; 

      int *r;
      r = x;
      return r;
  }
};

int main() {
  Array arr;

  int *temp = arr.get();

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cout << temp[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

This prints out 31 32765 0 0 0 0 -1989689609 32624 -989639072 32765 rather than
31 45 39 32 9 23 75 80 62 9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)  `x[]` is local to the function `get` and ceases to exist when it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a variable, that is allocated on stack, goes out of scope, it gets destroyed.
In your example function`Array::get`:

```
  int* get() {
      int x[] = { 31, 45, 39, 32, 9, 23, 75, 80, 62, 9 }; 

      int *r;
      r = x;
      return r;
  }
```

variable `x` gets destroyed. If you don't want this to happen, you can mark your variable with a `static` keyword: `static int x[] = ...` or allocate it on heap `int* x = new int[10]`. If you use the latter, make sure you free the memory when it's no longer used or use smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define this as a private member of class

```
private:
    int x[] = { 31, 45, 39, 32, 9, 23, 75, 80, 62, 9 };
```

or make it static when inside the function

```
static int x[] = { 31, 45, 39, 32, 9, 23, 75, 80, 62, 9 };
```

in both this cases this x array will persist and you will be able to get values out of it. Otherwise Your Get function will return only first member of the array and rest will be clear when exiting from scope of the function.