# What do you mean by Dangling Pointer Variable in C Programming?

Tags: c

Can any one explain what "dangling pointer" in C programming means?

When I'm trying to program with a dangling pointer it is getting errors.
Can anyone say what is dangling pointer?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? It would generally mean a pointer that points to something that is no longer valid.

Comment: https://www.qwant.com/?q=c+dangling+pointer

Comment: [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

A pointer pointing to a memory location that has been deleted (or freed) is called dangling pointer. There are three different ways where Pointer acts as dangling pointer.

1.`De-allocation of memory`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    free(ptr);

    ptr = NULL;
}
```

In this deallocating a memory  pointed by ptr is causes dangling pointer.after `free call` ptr becomes a dangling pointer.but after **ptr=NULL** it is no more a dangling pointer.

2.`Function Call`

```
#include<stdio.h>
  
int *fun()
{
int x = 5;
  
    return &x;
}
int main()
{
    int *p = fun();
    fflush(stdin);
printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

the pointer pointing to local variable becomes dangling when local variable is not static.**x** is local variable and goes out of scope after an execution of **fun()** is over.p points to something which is no valid anymore. so, it will print garbage value.but this problem can be solved using **static int x**.

3.`Variable goes out of scope`

v

```
oid main()
{
   int *ptr;
   
   
   {
       int ch;
       ptr = &ch;
   }
```

here ptr is a dangling pointer.

}

Comment: BTW - [do not cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)