# Long strings mangled for Idris to C++

Tags: c++, c, string, ffi, idris

I'm calling C++ from Idris. It's working fine, mostly, but while I can use short strings fine, long strings get mangled. Here's my code

```cpp
// C++
extern "C" {
    const char* foo() {
        std::string res = "foo";
        return res.c_str();
    }
}
```

and

```
-- idris
%foreign "C:foo,libfoo"
export
foo : String

main : IO ()
main = printLn foo
```

`"foo"` prints fine, but `"fooooooooooooooo"` prints `"\65533\65533\65533\SOH"`.

Comment: `return res.c_str();` returns a pointer to a temporary that no long exists once the function returns.  This is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Comment: This should be helpful too: https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#structs

Comment: @MarekR i'm curious why you suggest structs. I've got it working with `strdup` so I can stick with C-strings rather than adding C++ `string` into the FFI

Comment: This documents how memory should be managed. Procedure should be same for `struct` allocated on heap as for `char[]` allocated on heap. You have two choices, allocate on heap or change API in such way allocation is not needed.